# How to control the body content by clicking on header content in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to redirect using React Router as shown below:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";




function HeaderElements(props)
{
    let history = useHistory();

    function handleClick(link) {
        history.push(link);
    }
    return(
        <div className = "HeaderOptions" onClick = {(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(props.headerhrefs);
            handleClick(props.headerhrefs);
        }}>
        {props.title}
        </div>
    );
}
```

But when I click on the link as shown below:
[image]

The alert tells me about `props.headerrefs`

and after that instead of redirecting, it throws the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

[image]

Here's my app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';


import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import GlobalSiteConstants from './components/ConstantFiles/GlobalSiteConstants';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';
import LoginPage from './components/LoginPage';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <Header HeaderNames = {GlobalSiteConstants.HeaderNames}
    HeaderHrefs = {GlobalSiteConstants.HeaderHrefs}/>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Route exact path = "/"><HomePage / ></Route>
    <Route exact path = "/login"><LoginPage / ></Route>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**As you can see, my header is out of the Router and I feel that's what is causing issue. Can anyone please help me with this? I want to change below Header Route based on user's click.**

For example, my web structure is as follows:

---------Header-----------------

--------Content----------------

Where Header is common to all pages and content changes as follows:
"/" => home
"/login" => login page

and so on...

*I want to alter the `Content` part based on the click user makes. I know it can be achieved by conditional Rendering but can't we use Router here? Just Curious.*

Comment: If you found any solution, please update with an answer

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik you could follow the question in order to receive updates

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by putting `Header` into `BrowseRouter` in `app.js`.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';


import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import GlobalSiteConstants from './components/ConstantFiles/GlobalSiteConstants';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';
import LoginPage from './components/LoginPage';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Header HeaderNames = {GlobalSiteConstants.HeaderNames}
    HeaderHrefs = {GlobalSiteConstants.HeaderHrefs}/>
    <Route exact path = "/"><HomePage / ></Route>
    <Route exact path = "/login"><LoginPage / ></Route>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```